# Como recorrer objeto dentro de otro objeto en Angular 12

Tags: html, angular, json

Tengo un producto que tiene adicionales los cuales dentro poseen opciones y estos ultimos son los que quiero recorrer.

Este es el JSON que recibo de la peticion

```
{
    "06aa27a0-cc4f-11ec-b942-5fe5314f4dab": {
        "Descripcion": "Selecciona la salsa que mas te guste",
        "Maximo": 2,
        "Minimo": 0,
        "Nombre": "Salsas",
        "Opciones": {
            "046ae380-369e-11ed-ac1b-61f04f5d7304": {
                "Nombre": "Salsa blanca",
                "Precio": 200
            },
            "126ae380-369e-11ed-ac1b-61f04f5d7304": {
                "Nombre": "Salsa Roja",
                "Precio": 200
            }
        }
    },
    "e1c8c4f0-369d-11ed-ac1b-61f04f5d7304": {
        "Descripcion": "Elige el tamaño de tu papas fritas",
        "Maximo": 5,
        "Minimo": 0,
        "Nombre": "Papas fritas",
        "Opciones": {
            "046ae380-369e-11ed-ac1b-61f04f5d7304": {
                "Nombre": "Pequeño",
                "Precio": 400
            },
            "546ae380-369e-11ed-ac1b-61f04f5d7304": {
                "Nombre": "Grande",
                "Precio": 1400
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Almaceno la peticion a una variable llamada aditionals de la siguiente forma

```
public aditionals: any;
async getAditionals(){
    (await this.productsService.getAditionals('046ae380-369e-11ed-ac1b-61f04f5d7304'))
    .subscribe(
        (response) => { 
            this.aditionals = Object.values(response);
        },
        (error) => { 
            console.log(error); 
        }
    );
}
```

Asi es como estoy intentando recorrer la lista en el HTML

```
<mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let element of aditionals; let j = index" [attr.data-index]="j">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <mat-panel-title>
            <h6>{{ element.Nombre }}</h6>
        </mat-panel-title>
        <mat-panel-description>
            <h6>{{ element.Description }}</h6>
            <h6>{{ element.Minimo }}</h6>
            <h6>{{ element.Maximo }}</h6>
        </mat-panel-description>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <div class="row">// Aqui es el problema
          <div class="col-12" *ngFor="let key of element.Opciones">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">
                    <mat-form-field>
                        <mat-label>Nombre</mat-label>
                        <input matInput value="{{key.Nombre}}">
                    </mat-form-field>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6">
                    <mat-form-field>
                        <mat-label>Precio</mat-label>
                        <input matInput value="{{key.Precio}}">
                    </mat-form-field>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
</mat-expansion-panel>
```

Que estoy haciendo mal? Estoy intentando recorrer el Opciones del Adicional, pero obtengo el siguiente error

> Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type
> 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Como creo puede ser de utilidad dejo como resolvi este inconveniente.

Primero cree una interface llamada AditionalsOptions

```js
export interface AditionalsOptions {
    Nombre: string;
    Precio: number;
}
```

Posteriormente cree un pipe para filtrar el objeto en el html llamado valueOptions

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { AditionalsOptions } from '../interfaces/product/aditionals-options';

@Pipe({
  name: 'valueOptions',
  pure: false
})
export class ValueOptionsPipe implements PipeTransform {
  // El parametro object representa, los valores de las propiedades o indice
  transform = (objects: AditionalsOptions[] = []) => {
    return Object.values(objects);
  }
}
```

Y para finalizar recorri el html llamando al pipe creado anteriormente

```html
<div class="col-sm-12" *ngFor="let key of element.Opciones | valueOptions">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <mat-form-field>
                <mat-label>Nombre</mat-label>
                <input matInput value="{{( key.Nombre )}}">
            </mat-form-field>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <mat-form-field>
                <mat-label>Precio</mat-label>
                <input matInput value="{{ key.Precio }}">
            </mat-form-field>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tambien es posible utilizar el pipe `keyvalue`

Answer (score 1):

Tambien es posible hacerlo con el pipe `keyvalue`:

```html
<span>
  <p>Object</p>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let item of object | keyvalue">
  {{item.key}}:
  <br/> 
  <br/> 
      <span *ngFor="let item2 of item.value | keyvalue">
         
          {{item2.key}}:{{item2.value}}
        <br/> 
      </span>
<br/>
</ng-container>

</span>
```

## Acerca del pipe [`keyvalue`](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe)

> The output array will be ordered by keys. By default the comparator will be by Unicode point value. You can optionally pass a compareFn if your keys are complex types.

---

> La salida del array será ordenada por las llaves. Por defecto el comparador deberá ser de tipo unicode. Opcionalmente puedes pasarle una funcion `compareFn` si tus llaves son tipos complejos.

Te dejo un [ejemplo funcional aquí.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bzm2h6?file=src/app/pipe-key-value/pipe-key-value.component.ts)

Comment: Muy buena respuesta, bien completa, pero mi intencion era recorrer el sub objeto Opciones para obtener estas variantes. Es por ello que cree la interfaz y mi propio pipe para obtener esos valores.